# Passing complex JPA Entities to the controller with POJO

Tags: java, jpa, playframework, pojo

My team is coding an application that involves editing wikipedia-like pages.
It is similar to the problem we have with registration:

A straightforward implementation gives something like

```
public static void doRegistration(User user) {
//...
}
```

The user parameter is a JPA Entity. The User model looks something like this:

```
@Entity
public class User extends Model {

//some other irrelevant fields

@OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
public Collection<Query> queries;

@OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
public Collection<Activity> activities;
//...
```

I have read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1441523/jpa-pojo-as-data-object) and [there](http://groups.google.com/group/play-framework/browse_thread/thread/32a9246103a2d05/2f04d13c47aae32a?lnk=gst&q=POJO#2f04d13c47aae32a) that this fails. Now, in Play!, what is the best course of action we can take? There must be some way to put all that data that has to go to the server in one object, that easily can be saved into the database.

EDIT: The reason this fails is because of the validation fail. It somehow says "incorrect value" when validating collection objects. I was wondering if this can be avoided.

SOLUTION: Changing the Collection to List has resolved the issue. This is a bug that will be fixed in play 1.2 :)

Thanks beforehand

Comment: Are you implying that `Query` and `Activity` are not entities?

Comment: @Jeremy thanks for the swift answer, The collections all consist out of entities. The database is persistent and is operational.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this works. To be more clear, you can define a controller method like the one you wrote:

```
public static void doRegistration(User user) {
//...
}
```

That's completely fine. Just map it to a POST route and use a #{form} to submit the object, like:

```
#{form id:'myId', action:@Application.doRegistration()}
   #{field user.id} 
   [...]
#{/form}
```

This works. You may have problems if you don't add all the field of the entity in the form (if some fields are not editable, either use hidden inputs or a NoBinding annotation as described [here](http://www.playframework.org/documentation/1.1.1/controllers)).

**EDIT:** on the OneToMany subject, the relation will be managed by the "Many" side. That side has to keep the id of the related entity as a hidden field (with a value of object.user.id). This will solve all related issues.

Comment: I don't really understand it. The problem is that, for some reason, Play wont validate the collections in the User model. You say that problem can be fixed, just by adding the id of the user?

Because the registration works fine when I disable the validation

Comment: But then your problem is not with the method, but the validation (that wasn't clear from the question). You should try changing the Collection to List/Set. Otherwise, the class seems correct. Maybe you should add the code of all the related classes and the error message you are getting.

Comment: This was the greates comment in comment history! Changing the Collections to Lists seems to be resolving the issue. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't fail. If you have a running transaction, the whole thing  will be persisted. Just note that transactions are usually running within services, not controllers, so you should pass it from the controller to the service.